# Native prototypes vs $.extension()

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

At work, we use jQuery. Shortly after we started using it, I saw that a couple developers were adding functions to a file jquery-extensions.js. Inside, I found a whole bunch of methods added to `$` that essentially amount to static methods on jQuery. Here's a few:

```
$.formatString(str, args) {
    ...
}

$.objectToArray(obj) {
    ...
}
```

Etc. *None of them actually use anything to do with jQuery*. This struck me as odd.

Eventually, we needed a function in our library to localize dates. My solution was to create:

```
Date.prototype.toLocaleDate = function() {
    ...
}

Date.parseLocalDate = function() {
   ...
}
```

Shortly after doing this, I get a Sr. Developer coming up to me asking me what I think I'm doing. He tells me that here, where I work, we don't create prototypes because they're evil. The only reasons he gave was that they're fundamentally a poor language features because they "can be abused" and that it's confusing to see prototypes (e.g. how do I know new Date().toLocaleDate() is a prototype and not native ECMAScript). By using `$.formatString(...)` instead of `"blah blah".formatString(...)`, we're keeping it clear that anything with a $ is not part of native JavaScript.

Those reasons seem a bit silly, but I offered a compromise so he wouldn't have to remember whether a method was an prototype—prefix the prototype function name with `$`:

```
String.prototype.$format = function() {
    ...
}

"blah blah".$format(...);
```

That was quickly dismissed and now I'm having to add these $.myPrototypeAsAFauxStaticMethodOnjQuery() functions everywhere.

Am I the only one that thinks this practice is stupid?

Comment: They just want the `$`, if you get my drift.

Comment: "Am I the only one that thinks this practice is stupid?" No.  But... **do** make this a Community Wiki or it will be closed.  Better yet, ask this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Kirk Woll: what's the rep requirement for making own posts CW? (I know 100 is required to edit other CW posts.)

Comment: This "senior developer" is an idiot...so no, you're not the only one who thinks this is stupid, it's adding an unneeded dependency and really just makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: "Reopening classes" might get messy, but if a function is not related to jQuery it might be a better idea to keep them separately (e.g. `CompanyName.Util.OurMagicFormatters.formatString()`) /sarcasm

Comment: It's not so much about prototype objects *in general* being evil, but about modifying the prototype objects of "native" Javascript types. The Prototype library does this with wild abandon, and it ends up being both a good thing and a bad thing (particularly with respect to the modifications to `Object`). One approach you could take would be to extend the native Date object, which might not be too hard (won't work for Arrays unfortunately).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native prototypes debate is a bit tired, there are valid points on both sides, I'll try to summarize them in hope it might be useful to see the big picture.

**contra** There's no need to extend native prototypes. You've got everything you need.
 
**pro** JS standard library is scarce to the extreme. Arrays and strings are lacking many vital features.

**contra** Use functions or your own "namespaces".
 
**pro** Methods like `foo.trim()` are far more in the spirit of the language than functions like `org.blah.trim(foo)`. Everything is object in javascript and let it be that way.

**contra** Native JS objects are "reserved" for the language designers. Our methods can accidentally override newly added built-ins. 
**pro** Open objects is a great feature and it would be silly not to use it. A new Javascript version is not something that happens every day and additions to the standard are well known in advance.

**contra** Extending native prototypes is confusing, because there's no distinction between our and native methods. 
**pro** JS standard library is small and well documented. We javascript developers are supposed to know native methods' names.

**contra** Extending prototypes can lead to namespace conflicts. 
**pro** Yes, but this can happen with global functions or well-known global objects (like `$`) as well.

**contra** Custom methods are enumerable. 
**pro** Yes, but there's `hasOwnProperty` to the rescue. Wrap it in your own enumerator function and stop using raw `for..in` loops with objects.

(not a real answer, hence CW)

Answer (score 1):

1. Senior titles are often overrated.
2. There are a lot of people who don't understand prototypal inheritance.
3. Even though extending the prototype of native JavaScript objects is legal, don't do it. You run the risk of clashing with frameworks.
4. It doesn't make sense to hijack `$` for non-jQuery utility functions. Why not use the company's own namespace? If you need to be concise, use `$$` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not stupid!, But It's more beautiful to use prototype!, But then again who cares about beauty? Your code eventually will be scary and [will suck](http://www.girldeveloper.com/2010/07/your-code-sucks.html), But if it's well documented and **consistent** you'll never need to think about these issues!